# Trying to Run Azure Cognitive Search Sample App locally, getting error

Tags: azure, powershell, openai-api

I am trying to run this sample from the MS Azure Samples:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo

The repo comes with an installation script that creates all of the resources and deploys the project - I had no problem getting that to work.  The app is deployed to my tenant and I can use it without issue.

The problem is that I want to launch it locally so that I can make some UI changes and see them reflected immediately.  The instructions in the readme say to launch "start.ps1" in the "app" folder.  When I do that, everything is clean until the very end of the processing.  I am getting an error about an incomplete environment configuration.  The result is a completely empty page when I access it in the browser.

[image]

```
Starting backend

 * Serving Quart app 'app'
 * Debug mode: False
 * Please use an ASGI server (e.g. Hypercorn) directly in production
 * Running on http://localhost:50505 (CTRL + C to quit)
WARNING:azure.identity.aio._credentials.environment:Incomplete environment configuration. These variables are set: AZURE_TENANT_ID
INFO:azure.identity.aio._credentials.managed_identity:ManagedIdentityCredential will use IMDS
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request URL: 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=REDACTED&resource=REDACTED'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-identity/1.14.0 Python/3.11.6 (Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0)'
No body was attached to the request
INFO:azure.identity.aio._credentials.chained:DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from AzureCliCredential
[2023-11-03 11:01:00 -0400] [3544] [INFO] Running on http://127.0.0.1:50505 (CTRL + C to quit)
INFO:hypercorn.error:Running on http://127.0.0.1:50505 (CTRL + C to quit)
```

I've done some searching and found some threads that were similar to this (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680388/no-environment-configuration-found-defaultazurecredential) one).  IF I am understanding this correctly, when I go to launch it locally, a new environment is created and this environment might not see the same variables?  When I turned debugging on to a more verbose level, it appeared as though it saw the other variables that are in my .env file.

Any help our thoughts would be GREATLY appreciated. I posted the same question in the github repo, but others have had the same issue and have yet to see a response.

Comment: The issue was how the files are served up to the browser.  This fixed the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70741738/1347623